# Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a circular dependency between modules

Tags: nestjs

I have a circular dependency issue but I don't see where it's coming from. The whole error message reads as follows:

```
Nest cannot create the module instance. Often, this is because of a circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it.

(Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)
Scope [AppModule -> EntriesModule]
```

So I gather there's a circular dependency issue between the specified modules, namely the `AppModule` and `EntriesModule`. The `EntriesModule` is in the `AppModule` module's `imports` and it looks as follows:

```
@Module({
    providers: [
        EntryService,
        IsUniqueEntryTitle,
    ],
    imports: [
        AwsModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
            EntryEntity,
            CategoryEntity,
        ]),
        CategoriesModule,
        SharedModule,
    ],
    controllers: [
        EntryController,
    ],
    exports: [
        EntryService,
    ],
})
export class EntriesModule {}
```

As far as I understand the circular dependency error is thrown when module A depends on module B , that in turn, depends on module A. In other words they have each other in their imports. But seems like it's not the case here. Why am I getting this error then?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got what I was doing wrong. I forgot to remove the import statement in the header. I only removed it from the `imports` section of the module's decorator.